# python: can statement be inside expression?

Tags: python

I'm trying to implement a lazy property. Say, an object is initialize by `object._x = None`, and then I want to write something

```
@property
def x(self):
    return self._x or (init_x_value(); x)
```

so that the initializer is called only the first time the attribute is looked up.

In scala, an expression can contain statements. Is something similar possible in python. If not, is there any alternative way to implement it, or should I stick with `if-else`?

Comment: `init_x_value` returns `None` right?

Comment: As far as I know this can't be done, which is one of the reasons `lambda` is so limited in Python.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem: it could, just calculate the `_x` value and store it in the object

Comment: Assumed init_x_value() returns *None*, you could simply *or* it, resulting in *return self._x or init_x_value() or x*. I fail to see, however, why init_x_value() has to be called at all in a property routine. Is there no constructor available to do it?

Comment: No, you can't put a statement inside an expression, the relationship is *always* the other way around. Find a way to do what you want in an expression instead.

Answer (score 6):

If `init_x_value` **returns `None`**, you can simply use:

```
return self._x or init_x_value() or self._x
```

Note however, like [@3Doubloons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42203998/python-can-statement-be-inside-expression/42204098?noredirect=1#comment71577834_42204098) says in their comment, that if `self._x` is something *false-ish* like `None`, `[]` (an empty list), `()` an empty tuple, or a class which has overridden the `__bool__` method, it will move on to the init method wich can be computationally expensive.

In case `init_x_value` **returns the calculated `x`** value itself, you can even write it like:

```
return self._x or init_x_value()
```

This is because the `or` in Python is rather special: the `x or y` works like:

```
if bool(x):
    return x
else:
    return y
```

and `x` and `y` are generated lazily. Since `bool(None)` is `False` in the first case, it will thus check `self._x`. If `self._x` is `None`, it will proceed by calling `init_x_value()` since that method does not return anything it implicitly returns `None` which is not accepted by the `or`-chain either, so it finally resolves to the last `self._x` which is now set.

Comment: Nice, didn't occur to me to use double `or`. However, if want a statement and not a function call, no way it can be done, right??

Comment: @blue_note: not as far as I know, since an assignment has no outcome (it does not return anything).

Comment: You need to be careful with this approach. If `self._x` is falsey, `init_x_values` will be called each time.

Comment: @3Doubloons: I've incorporated your warning in the answer. But in that case the original question would already have to solve that. It is true that if for instance `._x` is `False`, or `[]` or `()` or something falsish, it will indeed move in the chain. But in the question it would also have done that.

Answer (score 5):

To answer the title question itself : no, in Python an expression can not contain a statement. period.

The proper pythonic way to write your getter is:

```
@property
def x(self):
    # assume _x defaults to None 
    if self._x is None:
        # here you can have has many statements as 
        # you like ;)
        self._x = init_x_value()
    return self._x
```

might not look as smart as triple 'or' or inline statements or whatever but it's as simple, straightforward, clear and *readable* as it can be.

Answer (score 1):

You can hide the statements in a function:

```
@property
def x(self):
    def initialize_and_return_x():
        init_x_value()
        return self._x
    return self._x or initialize_and_return_x()
```